# How to persist the session within the same azure powershell script?

Tags: azure, powershell

I am running a ps script (power shell 7) in Windows to programmatically extract a resource group as below:

```
Connect-AzureRmAccount -Subscription 'Demonstration Account'
$rg = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name 'psdemo-rg' -Location 'centralus'
```

The first line sort of works because it launches the browser for me to login. However there is a

```
Could not load type 'System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng' from assembly 'System.Core,
     | Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

When the second line executes I get

```
Run Connect-AzureRmAccount to login.
```

So this makes me think that the login doesn't seem to stick around. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Appreciate any suggestions

What I have tried:

I tried Connect-AzAccount to login instead but it's unrecognized...

Comment: This is not supposed to happen in general scenarios. I hope you're running the PowerShell session as an Admin. Meanwhile, you can try using `Enable-AzureRmContextAutosave` to retain your account context information.

Comment: Why do you hope he is running the powershell session as admin?  Doesn't seem like that should be necessary to to run these commands especially if the credentials to login to Azure are provided otherwise.

Comment: Does the below answer help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using `Netcore`, you check it using below command:

```
$PSVersionTable
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      6.0.4
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    v6.0.4
OS                             Microsoft Windows 6.3.9600
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

I don't think it has the class:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng
```

I also see there are previous issues related to this [#5785](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/5785), [#6629](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/6629).

I would recommend to try the `AzureRM.Netcore` or use `PS 5`.